# Troubleshooting web browser caching

Tags: javascript, caching

So I'm just about to go crazy with frustration over here. I'm building a simple web site: a static HTML page with linked JavaScript. The JS is updated often so naturally I expect to be able to upload a new .js file to the server - I'm using a web hotel - reload the page in my browser and get the new version. Except that I get the old file. The issue only happens on my computer as far as I know. I've tried reloading the page and disabling the JS cache in Chrome developer tools. The problem seems to go away if I wait several minutes and upload a new file. I don't have root access to the web server but can use PHP.

How do I proceed in finding the true cause of the problem?

**Update**: I found a workaround; to rename my index.html to index.php and (using PHP) append a unique number to the JavaScript file URL. Like this:

```
<script src="trafik.js?a=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

This forces the browser to reload the file. However my original question still stands, as I haven't found the cause and I don't know how to systematically approach the issue. Also it seems like an ugly solution to involve PHP just for this.

Comment: You keep devtools open, right? This option only works if you do. (But you probably already know that.)

Comment: Does hitting `ctrl-f5` (on windows) cause the javascript be reloaded?

Comment: You can try `ctrl + shifr + R` or `cmd` on Mac OSX to force cache refresh in Chrome. It helps sometimes! Either, you're relying on your server cache, which might be inaccurate.

Comment: If you're clearing your cache and the same JS is being loaded it's possible your ISP has a transparent cache installed. Try [Lagado's cache test](http://www.lagado.com/tools/cache-test)

Comment: I've been using Chrome with developer tools open and the "disable caching" checkbox checked. The reload buttons do absolutely nothing neither in Chrome nor Firefox nor IE9. I'm using windows vista. I've also tried the right-click menu on Chrome's reload button which is enabled when developer tools is open.

Comment: @MikeW Tried it just now, probably no proxy cache.

Comment: @Bigood sadly, there's no problem when I browse using my smartphone, so it's unlikely to be the web server.

Comment: Is it possible that differences in system time and file timestamps cause this?

Answer (score 0):

If you really disabled cache in your browser, it means the cached version is provided by server. So, it's a problem related to Apache (or Nginx, or any http server).

Maybe you can try to add a .htaccess file with those rules (mod_headers need to be enabled, hope it's a default setup on your webserver) :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I have a .htaccess file with this line: `Header add "disablecache" "true"`

Comment: You better avoid using `add` as stated in documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_headers.html), it could overlap an existing rule (and your rule could be ignored). Prefer using set, append or merge.